# Typescript type of MaterialTextfield

Tags: javascript, typescript, material-design, typescript-typings

I am creating my first react typescript app.
I found a some sample in pure javascript and wan't to write sth similar in typescript.

In [firebase javascript sample](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/database/scripts/main.js) we can see

```
addCommentForm.onsubmit = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  createNewComment(postId, firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName, uid, commentInput.value);
  commentInput.value = '';
  commentInput.parentElement.MaterialTextfield.boundUpdateClassesHandler();
};
```

I would like to do sth similar in **typescript**, I would like to create a function like below

```
function resetMaterialTextfield(element: HTMLInputElement) {
  element.value = '';
  element.parentNode.MaterialTextfield.boundUpdateClassesHandler();
}
```

**My question is:**

- How should I declare element, with what type, so that it had parentNode, parentElement attribute, and that parent had MaterialTextfield on which I could call boundUpdateClassesHandler()?
- From which library/framework does MaterialTextfield come from? What type is it? Where can I find documentation or some tutorial for this class and library?

Answer (score 0):

Use type assertion.
`(element.parentNode as TypeYouWant).MaterialTextfield.boundUpdateClassesHandler();`

Comment: I don't know TypeYouWant. What type could it be? In which library or framework is MaterialTextfield defined?

Comment: then just use `any`

Comment: I'm new to typescript/js, react and frontend dev, but I would find using  *any*, in the last resort, a nasty workaround but not a solution. If I were to do it such way what's the benefit of using typescript over javascript? If you find it a valid solution, could you please provide some link to doc or article supporting such attitude?